# MYSQL: Creating a function with multiple returns

Tags: mysql, function

Why is this function not working?

```
CREATE FUNCTION build_address(street VARCHAR(50), city VARCHAR(30), state CHAR(2), zipcode VARCHAR(10), country VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS VARCHAR(130)
    IF (street != '',
    IF (city != '',
    IF (state != '',
    IF (zipcode != '',
    IF (country != '',
    RETURN CONCAT(street, ', ', city, ', ', state, ' ', zipcode, ' ', country),
    RETURN CONCAT(street, ', ', city, ', ', state, ' ', zipcode)),
    RETURN CONCAT(street, ', ', city, ', ', state)),
    RETURN CONCAT(street, ', ', city)),
    RETURN CONCAT(street),
    IF (city != '',
    IF (state != '',
    IF (zipcode != '',
    IF (country != '',
    RETURN CONCAT(city, ', ', state, ' ', zipcode, ' ', country),
    RETURN CONCAT(city, ', ', state, ' ', zipcode)),
    RETURN CONCAT(city, ', ', state)),
    RETURN CONCAT(city),
    IF (state != '',
    IF (zipcode != '',
    IF (country != '',
    RETURN CONCAT(state, ' ', zipcode, ' ', country),
    RETURN CONCAT(state, ' ', zipcode)),
    RETURN CONCAT(state),
    IF (zipcode != '',
    IF (country != '',
    RETURN CONCAT(zipcode, ' ', country),
    RETURN CONCAT(zipcode),
    IF (country != '',
    RETURN CONCAT(country),
    RETURN '')))))))));
```

I'm about 99% certain that the parentheses are in the correct place. you can double check but I don't think that is the issue. I think the issue is that it is mad at me for having more than one return statement, but they are all within their own scope. From what I can tell this should work fine.

I don't know if this is important, but I am using phpMyAdmin and that is still on MySQL 5.6.21.

I am getting the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN CONCAT(street, ', ', city, ', ', state, ' ', zipcode, ' ', country),
>       RE' at line 7

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: take a street, city, state, zipcode, and country and build an address string. a lot of the addresses might be missing different parts so depending on what information is there, it will build the address differently.

Comment: Why? If the condition is correct it should goto the first return statement and if it is wrong, it should skip it and go to the next statement. I'm I not understanding how if statements work in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the [if function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) and [if statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html). You need the latter.

Also, this is way, way too much needlessly complicated. No sane human being will ever follow those crazy parenthesis. This can be written much simpler:

```
create function build_address(
    street varchar(50),
    city varchar(30),
    state char(2),
    zipcode varchar(10),
    country varchar(10)
)
returns varchar(130) deterministic
begin
  declare ret varchar(130);
  declare sep varchar(10);

  set ret = '';
  set sep = '';

  if street is not null and street != '' then
    set ret = concat(ret, sep, street);
    set sep = ', ';
  end if;

  if city is not null and city != '' then
    set ret = concat(ret, sep, city);
    set sep = ', ';
  end if;

  if state is not null and state != '' then
    set ret = concat(ret, sep, state);
    set sep = ' ';
  end if;

  if zipcode is not null and zipcode != '' then
    set ret = concat(ret, sep, zipcode);
    set sep = ' ';
  end if;

  if country is not null and country != '' then
    set ret = concat(ret, sep, country);
    set sep = ' ';
  end if;

  return ret;
end;
```

By the way - have you read [falsehoods programmers believe about addresses](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/)? Trying to split address into components like this is mostly a doomed idea. There **WILL** be someone who cannot fit their address in that format. The best way is to simply provide a textarea where the user can fill out their address free-form.